# Render enumeration value using code blocks

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want the value of jsonStr to be

```
"{submitOfferResult: 0}"
```

instead though it is

```
"{submitOfferResult: OFFER_ACCEPTED}"

//javascript
var jsonStr = "{submitOfferResult: <%=SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT.OFFER_ACCEPTED %>}";

//c#
public enum SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT
{
    OFFER_ACCEPTED = 0,
    QUALIFYING_OFFER_NOT_MET = 1,
    OFFER_ACCEPTED_NOT_HIGHEST_OFFER = 2,
    OSP_CLOSED = 3,
    AUTO_REJECTED = 4
}
```

Comment: .Net public member names (including enum values) should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Can't you just cast it? `(int)SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT.OFFER_ACCEPTED`

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - If you read the post you linked, it stated that integrating tag names in the question title is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the enum to a numeric type:

```
(int)SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT.OFFER_ACCEPTED
```

Answer (score 4):

Just cast to `int`:

```
var jsonStr = "{submitOfferResult: <%=(int) SUBMIT_OFFER_RESULT.OFFER_ACCEPTED %>}";
```

Otherwise it's calling `ToString()` on the enum value, which will use the name where possible.

Note that to follow .NET naming conventions, your enum would be:

```
public enum SubmitOfferResult
{
    OfferAccepted = 0,
    QualifyingOfferNotMet = 1,
    OfferAcceptedNotHighestOffer = 2,
    OspClosed = 3,
    AutoRejected = 4
}
```

And then:

```
var jsonStr = "{submitOfferResult: <%=(int) SubmitOfferResult.OfferAccepted %>}";
```

Comment: Thanks Jon,though I am compelled to address ".NET naming conventions" is quite a broad sweeping statement you just threw in the mix. Just because CamelCase is preferred these days doesn't mean   it is strongly recommended or required. My large code base has a convention that helps developers identify constant values that have a one to one with values in a Underscore/All Caps naming convention DB. I don't want any of my development team to have a non value producing OCD response to that particular of your answer and start renaming underscore to camelcase ;).

Comment: @Brian: It's not required, but it *is* strongly recommended. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx Note that your choice of ignoring the standard convention means that your developers will see very different names for "internal" code and .NET framework code (and 3rd party libraries, which are *very* likely to conform to the normal naming conventions). It's also likely to be against what anyone you hire will be used to...

Comment: I disagree Jon. You say it is strongly recommended and an Microsoft article does too but what do these naming conventions have to do with creating business value? I am an entrepreneur and a programmer. Programmers are perfectionists and this can get in the way of creating value. Yes, underscore is an eye sore. But as an entrepreneur if I find out a developer did a solution wide find and replace for something that worked and also had a purpose because he read a Microsoft article I would have a second thought of firing that developer. Instead, I would tell that developer: ...

Comment: The underscore convention you removed was the only way any developer can know there is a one to one relation between the C# enum and values in the database for our software. There is nothing, not familiarity, not convention, not OCD or perfection that outweighs the business value you would have created by leaving that working code alone and instead devoting that lost time to a feature or bug fix for our upcoming deadline.

Comment: @Brian: Well, suit yourself - but I'll continue recommending that C# developers follow the nearly global conventions recommended by Microsoft. And if I were considering joining a company, I would be put off by a decision to ignore well-established conventions. Maybe it's too late to change it now in your code base, but that in no way means it's a good thing. (Consider that the search and replace may well take less time than the maintenance *distraction* of unconventional code.)

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts Jon,in the past I would have agreed with you more.I almost didn't consider working for my current company simply because the code base was in VB.NET and that would have been the biggest mistake as my quality of life, pay and freedom our over the top rare now. Over time, hating that VB.NET I learned to just ignore my preferences and what I considered an eye sore or bad form, and focus on making things work,scale and last.It does not matter the language or the style you write it in, as long as it is readable, logical, makes common sense and delivers ROI.

Comment: @Brian: Whereas I view the style you write in as absolutely crucial to writing readable code. Anyway, I think we'll have to agree to disagree on how important consistency is - including consistency between "your" code and the platform you're working with.

Comment: Oh and just so you know I am "upping" your comments, I don't think anyone else is pay attention to us lol

Comment: I can't help but think how ludicrous it is that you would consider not working for a company simply because they had an all caps, underscore naming convention lol.

Comment: @Brian: I said it would put me off. It wouldn't be enough to convince me on its own, but it would be a bad sign... in the same way that not embracing automated testing would be, for example. You were the one saying you'd "have a second thought" of *firing* a developer for having the temerity to follow industry-standard conventions.

Comment: yes I did Jon. I understand your viewpoint for sure, I think I also mentioned how I almost didn't take my current job because much of the code base was in VB.NET. I think it has been quite a long day and I let are thread get under my skin for no real reason as I do you understand what you are saying ;).